# What is the practical difference between read_csv and read.csv? When should one be used over another?

Tags: r, csv, readr

I often work with comma separated values, and was curious to the differences between `read_csv()` and `read.csv()`.

Are there any practical differences that could shine light on the situational usage of both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoted from [the introduction page.](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-import.html)

11.2.1 Compared to base R

If you’ve used R before, you might wonder why we’re not using `read.csv()`. There are a few good reasons to favour readr functions over the base equivalents:

They are typically much faster (~10x) than their base equivalents. Long running jobs have a progress bar, so you can see what’s happening. If you’re looking for raw speed, try `data.table::fread()`. It doesn’t fit quite so well into the tidyverse, but it can be quite a bit faster.

They produce tibbles, they don’t convert character vectors to factors*, use row names, or munge the column names. These are common sources of frustration with the base R functions.

They are more reproducible. Base R functions inherit some behaviour from your operating system and environment variables, so import code that works on your computer might not work on someone else’s.

---

*Note that from [`R 4.0.0`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html)

> R [...] uses a `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` default, and hence by default no longer converts strings to factors in calls to `data.frame()` and `read.table()`.

Answer (score 5):

read_csv() reads comma delimited numbers. It reads 1,000 as 1000.

[original numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEjDI.png)

[read by read_csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dhzf.png)

[read by read.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxPgj.png)